# copy folder structure to another structure with data in linux

Tags: bash, centos

I need to migrate my one server data to another server. But in new server folder structure bit different from old

```
Old server   /opt/myapp/1999/2020/03/01/my.txt
             /opt/myapp/1980/2019/02/01/my1.txt
```

```
New server  /opt/myapp/19/99/2020/03/01
            /opt/myapp/19/80/2019/02/01
```

I need to create script to map relevant path and migrate data.

I can't change new server folder structure due to app limitation.

Comment: I really suggest you to avoid doing this. If you will, this imply a lot of overhead changes inside the code.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at GNU tar's option `--transform`.

Comment: @Cyrus seem this one useful. i will try